# Android dimens for Nexus S and Nexus 5

Tags: android

I need styles folder (for dimens) for Nexus S and for Nexus 5. I try to use folder `styles-sw320dp` and others, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not use density folders? (hdpi, xhpdi...)

Comment: Nexus S is 4 inches, which folder I should use? styles-hdpi?

Comment: If im not wrong Nexus S has 233 dpi so it should fall into hdpi, you can use "-hdpi" for any resource type (layout, values, drawable...)

Answer (score 2):

Try **layout-xhdpi** for **Nexus S**.

And for **Nexus 5** try **layout-xxhdpi**.

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

For Nexus S - drawable-hdpi

And Nexus 5 - drawable-sw380dp-xhdpi

may be it work for you